# MATLAB: combining cells based on same values within cell elements

Tags: matlab, cell, element, equals

I have a cell with values like:
[1,2][4,5][2,8][1,9][5,2][6,7]
Which I would like converted to:
[1,2,4,5,8,9][6,7]
Basically, where one value in one element is equal to another cell element value I would like both elements combined into a new element...along with any other elements that have a value equal to any values in that element...so [1,2] would absorb [2,5] which would in turn absorb [4,5].

I have the code below so far which seems to at least create elements which contain the full groups (1,2,4,5,8,9), but also contains partial elements and duplicates (1,2)(1,2,4),etc. and does not contain elements without similar value partners (6,7). Any advice? Thanks

```
            TooClose2=[];
            for i=1:length(TooClose)
                TooClose2temp=[];
                for j=1:length(TooClose)
                    if i~=j
                        for h=1:length(TooClose{i})
                            if TooClose{i}(h)==TooClose{j}(h)
                                TooClose2temp(end+1)=TooClose{j}(1);
                                TooClose2temp(end+1)=TooClose{j}(2);
                            end   
                        end   
                    end
                end
                TooClose2{end+1}=TooClose2temp;
            end
```

Comment: And each cell has always two elements?

Comment: In the original cell, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but … We go through all unassigned elements, find matches (i.e. elements with a shared member), and assign group IDs (see comment). Finally, from those group IDs we iteratively construct the output cell. NB this algorithm should work for cells `elements` where elements have arbitrary length.
One obvious improvement would be to have the helper function only look at elements whose index is greater than `current_i`.

```
function [unified_elements, groups] = findGroups(elements)
    groups = zeros(size(elements));
    %// Find matches for unassigned elements
    for ii = 1:numel(groups)
        if groups(ii) == 0
            groups = fe(ii, elements, groups);
        end
    end
    %// Loop over all groups ...
    u_groups = unique(groups);
    n_groups = numel(u_groups);
    unified_elements = cell(1, n_groups);
    for i_group = 1:n_groups
        g_id = u_groups(i_group);
        %// ... and iterativeliy add the elements from that group to unified_elements
        for el = elements(groups==g_id)
            unified_elements{i_group} = union(unified_elements{i_group}, el{1});
        end
    end
end
%// Helper function that finds elements with shared members for a given element
%// If any of those elements with shared members has a group assigned, assign
%// it to all matches. Otherwise, use new group ID.
function groups = fe(current_i, elements, groups)
    next_g = numel(unique(groups));
    dc = cellfun(@(c) numel(intersect(c, elements{current_i})) > 0, elements);
    matching_groups = groups(dc);
    if any(matching_groups)
        groups(dc) = matching_groups(find(matching_groups, 1));
    else
        groups(dc) = next_g;
    end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can find list of all numbers in your arrays go through them one by one and merge all arrays that have that number in common:

```
C=unique(cell2mat(A));
for k=1:numel(C)
    I = find(cellfun(@(x) ismember(C(k), x), A));
    if numel(I)>1
        A{I(1)} = unique(cell2mat(A(I)));
        A(I(2:end)) = [];
    end
end
```